# Can't manage button's size properly using Constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to get 3 columns of ImageButtons using a ScrollView and Constraint layout;
I managed to get it right for my first column (buttons between guideline and guideline2), but somehow ImageButtons from the second column aren't the same size, even though I tried to keep it the same size (so ImageButtons between guideline3 and guideline 6).

Here's the code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello !"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/forest"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="forêt"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/tree"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/train"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline5" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_forest"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/forest"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/forest"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/train"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="train"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/train"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/forest"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/campfire" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_train"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/train"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/forest"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/forest"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/train"
            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/campfire"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="campfire"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/campfire"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/train"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/night" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_campfire"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/campfire"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/train"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/train"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/campfire"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/night"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="night"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/night"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/campfire"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/water" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_night"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/night"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/campfire"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/campfire"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/night"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/water"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="water"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/tree"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/night"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/river" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_water"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/night"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/water"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/water"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/night"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/river"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="Image de l'riviere"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/river"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/water"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/walk" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_river"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/river"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/water"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/water"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/river"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/walk"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="campfire"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/walk"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/river" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_walk"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/walk"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/river"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/river"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/walk"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rain"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="forêt"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/rain"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/train"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline5" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_rain"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/forest"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/rain"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/car"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="car"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/car"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/heartbeat"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline5" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/heartbeat"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="heartbeat"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/night"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/car"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/thunder" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thunder"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="thunder"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/night"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/heartbeat"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/whitenoise" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_thunder"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/thunder"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/heartbeat"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/heartbeat"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/thunder"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/whitenoise"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="whitenoise"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/night"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/thunder"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/pinknoise" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_whitenoise"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/whitenoise"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/thunder"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/thunder"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/whitenoise"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/pinknoise"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="pinknoise"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/night"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/whitenoise"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tapping" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_pinknoise"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/pinknoise"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/whitenoise"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/whitenoise"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pinknoise"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/tapping"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="tapping"
            android:background="@drawable/off"
            android:src="@drawable/night"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pinknoise"
            />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_tapping"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:progressTint="#ededed"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tapping"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/pinknoise"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pinknoise"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tapping"
            />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.385" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.10" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.635" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.70" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is a screen of the buttons: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkNiC.png)
I've tried different size of picture, modifying length, height, change guideline, ask GPT but I can't find the problem.

Comment: Are your drawables all the same size? Try removing adjust view bounds to see what that looks like. You can also try different scale types to see if one of those works for you.

Comment: Your constraints are not properly connected, especially the seekbar constraints on the middle column.